# Why the ROC I get from WEKA GUI is not similar to other ROC curves

Tags: machine-learning, weka, roc

[This is the ROC Curve that I get from weka GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rngi1.jpg)

[But this is the ROC curve that others get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBohJ.jpg)

Please help me to get the 2nd ROC curve that look nicer than my ROC curve :)

Comment: You probably have a classifier with binary output. You need a continuous output. Please give more information about your classifier.

Comment: Ya it is a binary classifier

Comment: I don't believe you need continuous output to make your ROC curve look like that. It could be that you don't have enough instances to make your curve as 'smooth' as the second example.